# Building an array from a list of options

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I currently have the following code which locates the `Show` id, then the elements in the `option` tags beneath and prints them out one by one.

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.id("Show"));
            List<WebElement> options = dropDown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));


            for (WebElement el : options) {
                System.out.println(el.getAttribute("text"));
            }
```

How can I modify it so that it builds up an array of all the text elements, instead of printing them out one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare another array (or list, depending on your preference) and change your System.out.println() statement.

For a List of whatever object the text attribute is:

```
for(WebElement el : options){
    secondList.Add(el.getAttribute("text"));
}
```

For an array, it would be easiest using indexing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < options.Size(); i++){
    secondArray[i] = options.Get(i).getAttribute("text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In WebDriver we've a method in [Select](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html) class to get all the options available in select tag.

```
List<WebElement> options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Show"))).getOptions();
```

To get all the option values arrays follow below logic.

```
public String[] getOptions() {
   String optionValues="";
   List<WebElement> options = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Show"))).getOptions();
   for(WebElement eachOption : options) {
       optionValues+=eachOption.getText()+",";
   }
   return optionValues.split(",");
}
```